# Get the amount of conflicts between two arrays [Divide and Conquer]

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matching, divide-and-conquer

I'm currently working on a project which involved getting the amount of conflicts between two arrays. This means the differences in order in which certain numbers are placed in the array. Each number only occurs once and the two array's are always the same size.

For example:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[4,3,2,1]
```

These two arrays have 6 conflicts:

- 1 comes for 2 in the first array, but 2 comes for 1 in the second, so conflict + 1.
- 1 comes for 3 in the first array, but 3 comes for 1 in the second, so conflict + 1.
- etc.

I've tried certain approaches to make an algorithm which computes the amount in O(n log n). I've already made one by using Dynamic Programming which is O(N²), but I want an algorithm which computes the value by Divide and Conquer.

Anyone has any thought on this?

Comment: These conflicts are called "inversions" in the literature. Google "count inversions in array". It helps if you remap the numbers such that the first array is `[1,2,...,n]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `self balancing binary search tree` for finding the number of conflicts ("inversions").
Lets take an `AVL tree` for example.

Initialize `inversion count` = 0.

Iterate from `0 to n-1` and do following for every `arr[i]`

Insertion also updates the result. Keep counting the number of greater nodes when tree is traversed from root to leaf.

When we insert arr[i], elements from arr[0] to arr[i-1] are already inserted into AVL Tree. All we need to do is count these nodes.
For insertion into AVL Tree, we traverse tree from root to a leaf by comparing every node with arr[i[].

When arr[i[ is smaller than current node, we increase inversion count by 1 plus the number of nodes in right subtree of current node. Which is basically count of greater elements on left of arr[i], i.e., inversions.

**Time complexity** of above solution is `O(n Log n)` as AVL insert takes `O(Log n) time.`